# OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility unable to continue

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

We are testing this utility performing a TFS 2012 to VSO version control data migration.

All seemed to be right, but after 18 hours of work, process have stopped after passed 9018 of 9295 chagesets. There is 1/9295 changesets pending for retry, with 'OH-SCM-009: Error ocurred while sync. GetAndDownloadFile : TF14124 (...)' message.

Every time we rerun the process it stops after some minutes :s

Any idea?

Thank you in advance!!!

News!!! After some digging, the problems seems to be in the source TFS, since when we try to get the particular changeset that cause the problem, we get the same error: "TF14124: The content for changeset XXXXXX of the file '$/***********' was destroyed. Please try again using a later version of this item." Any way to aviod this matter? It is impossible to delete changesets, and even if rollback it, utility get stuck with it again ...

Once again, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that in your TFS environement, files/changesets were destroyed using the **tf destroy** command with **/keephistory** parameter. Which typically destroys the files and it's contents, but keeps the changeset history intact The OpsHub utility migrates historic data sequentially and hence when it trying to fetch data based on Changeset details, it runs into problems for destroyed files.

There could be a way to ignore such files. We'll do a feasibility study for that. Until then, could you please share us your logs (to email ovsmu@opshub.vom)